# С# реализация коллекции

Tags: c#

Как реализовать коллекцию где ключ типа int и ему соответствуют 2 значения object и string?

Comment: `Dictionary<int, Tuple<Object, String>>` ?

Comment: Надо попробовать.

Comment: Хотя лучше бы наверное специальный класс завести для элемента коллекции, но кортеж проще, конечно.

Comment: Недостаточно данных. Какие требования к этой коллекции? Какая у неё должна быть асимптотика? Какой интерфейс? И много других вопросов возникает.

Answer (score 2):

Для хранения значения

```csharp
public class MyDataItem
{
   public object ObjectValue { get; set; }
   public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

И сама коллекция-словарь [`Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)

```csharp
Dictionary<int, MyDataItem> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyDataItem>();
```

Создать элемент

```csharp
MyDataItem item = new MyDataItem { ObjectValue = new object(), StringValue = "my string" };
```

или так

```csharp
MyDataItem item = new MyDataItem();
item.ObjectValue = new object();
item.StringValue = "my string";
```

Добавить в словарь, например с ключом `948`.

```csharp
dictionary.Add(948, item);
```

Взять из словаря

```csharp
MyDataItem newItem = dictionary[948];
Console.WriteLine(newItem.StringValue);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
my string
```